# χ 2 distribution with 50 degrees of freedom. Compute approximate value of P(49 < Y < 51). (whole question in body its long)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

`Let Y bar denote the mean of a random sample of size 100 from a χ 2 distribution with 50 degrees of freedom. Compute an approximate value of P(49 < Y < 51).`

I've been away from statistics for two semesters so this stuff is really difficult for me now. I don't really remember how to approach these problems anymore and I feel like I have a lot of gaps in my knowledge. Ideally I'd like to see the step by step process on this so I can apply this to other problems that are relatively similar.

Comment: The $\chi^2$ distribution is approximately normal.  You are expected to find the mean and standard deviation, then use that and you z-score table to get the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The central limit theorem says that the average of $Y_1,...,Y_n$ where Y's are independent and identically distributed (iid) having common mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$ will be approximately normally distributed $\bar Y\sim N(\mu, \frac {\sigma^2} n)$ for n at least around 20 to 30. The question asks you to use the Central Limit Theorem to approximate $P(49<\bar Y<51)$. As you know $Y\sim ChiSq(k=50)$ with mean k=50 and variance 2k=100.

You get:

$$\begin{split}Z&\approx\frac{\bar Y-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt n}\\&=\frac{\bar Y-k}{\sqrt{2k}/\sqrt {100}}\\
&=\frac{\bar Y-50}{1}\text {is approximately normally distributed}\end{split}$$

$$\begin{split}Z_1&=\frac{51-50}{1}\text{ find the upper bound}\\
&=1\\
Z_2&=\frac{49-50}{1}\text{ find the lower bound}\\
&=-1\end{split}$$

Now you must calculate the area under the normal distribution between -1 and 1. You can use a table or use R:

```
> pnorm(1)-pnorm(-1)
[1] 0.6826895
```

Comment: can you explain the step where you replace μ and σ with k and 2k? I can tell that k is 50 but where are you getting it from? The degrees of freedom? I can see that 50 is = to degrees of freedom which is in turn = to μ  but isnt σ^2 equal to 2*50 so σ is 10
Making the equation (Y - 50 ) / 1

Comment: Right-sorry for forgetting to take the square root. Every distribution has a parameter, for chi-squared it's the degrees of freedom, $k$. See post for some edits. For a chi-squared distribution, the mean is $k$ and variance is $2k$, which is why I replaced them

Comment: Kind of late but I am in the process of learning R and reviewing distributions of stuff

I understand that pnorm(1) means F(Y) P( Y <= 1) right? As in probability of every event less than 1 occurs. what I want to understand is what the 1 indicates here.  When I look up PNORM on the internet I only find uses with 3 parameter those being SD and mean.  What exactly am I doing when I do pnorm(1) and does this affect my problem? I have an SD of 10 and a mean of 50. Do i not need to incorporate that into the code?

Comment: Bro you already standardized the Z’s when you subtracted the mean and divided by the standard deviation of $\bar Y$. pnorm(1) is equivalent to pnorm(1,0,1), and yes it’s the area to the left of the standard normal density at z=1. You know the bell shaped curve. You could have also done pnorm(51,50,1) as the this is for not standard normal but you specify the mean and standard deviation. It’s usage is pnorm(x, mean=0, std=1) defaults mean you don’t have to specify them is optional.